# What do you call an unsupported roof that juts out over the entrance to a building?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Here is a sample picture:

> [image: Okay]

Do we call this a cantilevered roof? Or is there a more apt description?

Comment: It *is* a cantilevered roof, and that's OK for an engineer but hardly a punter-friendly description. What are the circumstances you want to use the term?

Comment: It is sometimes called a **canopy**, but it is not always cantilevered (it can be supported by brackets or poles).

Comment: In response to Andrew, the context is a story that I'm working on. I had come across the term 'cantilevered roof' online, but wasn't sure if it was appropriate for a general audience, or if, strictly speaking, it would only be understood by architects and engineers.

Comment: @CluelessKid Your elucidations should go into the question, which needs to stand alone without the need for comments (especially comments on an answer).

Comment: In a story, there wouldn't be any expectation to be told whether the roof was supported or cantilevered. There would be an expectation of location, function, and perhaps style and size. *Cantilevered* would be widely understood, but would likely be regarded as a curious detail if you weren't devoting a couple paragraphs to describing the thing.

Comment: It's just a canopy or in some places awning.

Comment: Duh!  Of course this is a **marquee**.  Only user @KeithMcClary had the thought!

Comment: FYI a famous / unusual example of this: the most famous existing early renaissance building, the Hospice de Beaune, has a really strange one of these (ie, fabricated in the 1400s) at the front over the door.  (It's a little hard to google up images since most images are the famous interior, or roofs.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more generic word for that would be **overhang**, defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overhang) as '*a projection of the roof or upper story of a building beyond the wall of the lower part*'

Comment: I should add that the description of this roof is not destined for a technical text, but rather sets the scene for a story that I'm working on. I had stumbled across the word "cantilevered roof," but wasn't sure whether readers would automatically associate that term with the type of building in question (in other words, if it would only be understood by architects and engineers). Hope that helps.

Comment: It’s a canopy. Cantilevered roof is not rare, it’s just not the right word here.

Comment: I know that this answer has been accepted but I'm afraid that I don't agree. An overhang is part of a more complex structure, either an upper storey or a roof covering at least part of the building itself. The structure in the photo exists only to cover the space outside the doorway.

Comment: I feel this is now a pretty good and excellent answer.  I understand BoldBen's point (so, just "canopy" would be better) but, Ben, I do feel the word is sometimes used "ex nihilo" like that.

Answer (score 8):

### [Canopy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/canopy)

> *Architecture* A projection or shelter that resembles a roof.
>
> ‘they mounted the station steps under the concrete canopy’

Comment: I think of something triangular and pointy (or at least hung) personally

Answer (score 6):

A [marquee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_(structure)) is most commonly a structure placed over the entrance to a hotel, theatre, casino, train station, or similar building. It often has signage stating either the name of the establishment or, in the case of theatres, the play or movie and the artist(s) appearing at that venue.
[image: Marquee]

In the OED:

[image]

Comment: This is clearly a good technical term for it, but would most non-technical readers understand?  (I'd immediately think of a big tent…)  — Mind you, it's interesting to see the origin for the old `<marquee>` HTML tag, for those of us who suffered it in the Web's early days…

Comment: @RedSonja I'm afraid you are utterly incorrect.  Simply glance in the OED.  The first and primary meaning is exactly the subject of this page.

Comment: @gidds - could there be a Brit/US thing going on?  It is extremely common to talk of marquees (as in "Broadway"), very few people call a "party tent" a marquee.

Comment: @Fattie Wiktionary [agrees](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marquee) with the OED quote you've added: it marks the big-tent meaning as ‘Britain, Australia, New Zealand’, and the canopy meaning (and its generalisation to scrolling lights) as ‘US’.  So yes, the term does seem to have strong regional differences, and it only provides a good answer to the question in some areas.

Comment: @gidds, yes, you make a fine point. I must say that *in the UK* I hear the discussed meaning (indeed, just as in the very British tube picture there!) but of course experiences vary.  (purely FWIW I personally dismiss wikis as a source.)

Comment: @Fattie OED, like M-W, is a historical dictionary. It lists senses of a word in order of the dates of their first mention (well, first discovered mention) in print. The first-mentioned sense may well now be archaic or even obsolete. I'd say the term  'the primary meaning' is better applied to the most idiomatic usage nowadays; Lexico, CED, Macmillan, AHD, and CED list senses in order of idiomaticity (as determined by their constant research; they may at times disagree). // Example sentences I've found seem to suggest that the 'pre-eminent' sense is primary, then the large tent, then ....

Comment: An in-depth Google 1-gram search shows a preponderance for virtual senses (the Photoshop tool, pre-eminence), and a pretty rigid breakdown between 'BrE' ('the primary version'?) and 'AmE'.

Comment: I stand corrected and delete my comment

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ("historical") that's a very excellent point, good one.  {As a curiosity I wonder if they use the same paradigm in the OED-seen-in-Apple-desktops.)  {If you just bring up "Dictionary" in MacOS, it's one they license from OED.}

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (ngrams) there's the inevitable problem on this site that written usages can be a guide to, but can be unrelated to, spoken usage.  Anyway, all valuable stuff

Comment: Just a minor detail, the marquee (/whatever!) in the photo, ie over the filthy street, is indeed supported visibly (by the relatively discrete metal bars). If some fancy-pants architectural historian arrives on this page, she will probably be outraged by us not considering that utterly different from the no-support one in the OP  :)

Answer (score 3):

I am blind and so cannot see the picture, but if it's some kind of permanent installation I would usually think of the description as being a 'portico': a structure consisting of a roof supported by columns at regular intervals, typically attached as a porch to a building.

However if it's just something made of cloth and supported by a couple of angled braces from the building itself then canopy would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: This is a good guess, but OP's example doesn't have any supporting columns. It's only supported where it attaches to the building.

Comment: I'd go for porch or portico, actually. It seems the language is missing a more exact word (see German "Vordach")

Answer (score 0):

While an *overhang* is the most technically correct answer, I think that more people would be likely to call it an **awning**, defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awning) as "*a rooflike cover extending over or in front of a place (as over the deck or in front of a door or window) as a shelter*".

While it is most commonly used for fabric over shop fronts, that was my first thought on seeing the picture.

Comment: I considered *awning* at first, but the thing in the picture isn't an awning. An awning is usually a piece of fabric stretched over a terrace.

Comment: An awning can be the same thing as in the question, but made of fabric (or made to look like fabric). So awning is a subset of whatever it is. I'd go for porch.

Comment: A porch has supports, and is often enclosed as almost its own room, and while an awning is most often fabric, a simple google search for `solid awning` comes up with a lot of results. I think the biggest (common use) difference in awnings is that the most commonly used ones are retractable (though that's not part of the definition) :-)

Comment: No doubt this is culturally connoted, but awning was the word that sprang immediately to my mind, and if you asked me to _define_ awning the key characteristics would be (a) cantilevered ie supported by torsional forces on the wall to which it attaches or tensile support anchored higher on the wall and (b) not part of the roof or upper floor.